# How to split the string on first vertical bar after first comma?

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a string like:

string1: http://localapp/lkasdjasd/answers/156, Lorem ipsum dolor? is it Lorem, nah? | Here is the answer

Need to split the string on first vertical bar after first comma:

1. key: 156
2. string1: Lorem ipsum dolor? is it Lorem, nah?
3. string2: Here is the answer

```
arr   = line.split(',')
key   = arr[0].split('/')[-1].to_i
title = arr[1]
desc  = arr[2]
```

So far I figured out only how to get the key

Comment: [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#split-method) takes an optional _limit_: `line.split(',', 2)` returns an array of 2 substrings: the part before the first comma and everything after. You can then split the 2nd substring again on `|` to get title and desc. (you might want to `strip` whitespace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```rb
/\A(?:[^,]*[^\d,])?(\d+),([^|]*)\|\s*(.+)/
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/zuzUXvs6JDevyw). *Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:[^,]*[^\d,])?` - an optional sequence of zero or more non-commas and then a char other than a digit and comma
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `,` - a comma
- `([^|]*)` - Group 2: zero or more non-pipe chars
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.+)`  - Group 3: one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

See a [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/4r0RCT):

```rb
s = 'http://localapp/lkasdjasd/answers/156, Lorem ipsum dolor? is it Lorem, nah? | Here is the answer'
/\A(?:[^,]*[^\d,])?(?<key>\d+),(?<title>[^|]*)\|\s*(?<desc>.+)/ =~ s
puts "Key: #{key}\nTitle: #{title}\nDescription: #{desc}"
```

Output:

```
Key: 156
Title:  Lorem ipsum dolor? is it Lorem, nah? 
Description: Here is the answer
```

Answer (score 0):

I vote for the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69299320/13841038
on which you can call `.to_i` and `.strip` while printing

```
key.to_i
title.strip
desc.strip
```

If you don't prefer regex, then below snippet is a modified version of your solution

```
str = "http://localapp/lkasdjasd/answers/156, Lorem ipsum dolor? is it Lorem, nah? | Here is the answer"

pipe_arr   = str.split('|')
arr        = pipe_arr[0].split(',')

key        = arr[0].split('/')[-1].to_i
title      = (arr[1] + ',' + arr[2]).strip
desc       = pipe_arr[1].strip
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answers what is asked for in the title and in the third line, which are unambiguous. That is not consistent with the desired result, however.

```
r = /\A([^,]*,[^|]*)\|(.*)/x
```

```
"Little Miss Muffett, sat on | a tuffet".scan(r).first
  #=> ["Little Miss Muffett, sat on ", " a tuffet"]
```

```
"Little | Miss, Muffett, sat on |, a | tuffet".scan(r).first
  #=> ["Little | Miss, Muffett, sat on ", ", a | tuffet"]
```

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
r = /
    \A       # match beginning of string
    (        # begin capture group 1
      [^,]*  # match 0 or more chars other than a comma
      ,      # match a comma
      [^|]*  # match 0 or more chars other than a pipe
    )        # end capture group 1
    \|       # match a pipe
    (.*)     # match 0 or more chars and save to capture group 2
    /x       # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

See [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) for an explanation of how the method treats regular expressions that contain capture groups.<sup>1</sup>

---

A second way, that does not use a regular espression, is to use [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-index):

```
def split_it(str)
  i = str.index(',')
  return nil if i.nil?
  j = str.index('|', i+1)
  j.nil? ? nil : [str[0,j-1], str[j+1..-1]]
end
```

```
split_it("Little Miss Muffett, sat on | a tuffet")
  #=> ["Little Miss Muffett, sat on", " a tuffet"]
```

```
split_it("Little | Miss, Muffett, sat on |, a | tuffet")
  #=> ["Little | Miss, Muffett, sat on", ", a | tuffet"]
```

<sup>1 An alternative, which I will give without explanation, is the following: "Little | Miss, Muffett, sat on |, a | tuffet".match(/\A[^,]*,[^|]*\K|/) && [$`, $'] #=> ["Little | Miss, Muffett, sat on ", ", a | tuffet"].</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
s = 'http://localapp/lkasdjasd/answers/156, Lorem ipsum dolor? is it Lorem, nah? | Here is the answer'
answer = s.gsub(/.*,.*[|]/,'')
```